# Writing in Cartesian tensor form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, tensors

Write the following in Cartesian tensor form

$$(1) \nabla (\operatorname{div} G) \times \nabla\Omega$$
$$(2) (\operatorname{curl}(F)\times G)\cdot \nabla(Φ)$$

I have answers for these two questions, however I do not understand how to show it step by step.

Comment: Please LaTeX it up.Its too hard too read.

Comment: what do you need to prove?

Answer (score 1):

**On the first expression**.

Let $G=G(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ be a vector field in $\mathbb R^3$, with $$G(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\left(G_1(x_1,x_2,x_3), G_2(x_1,x_2,x_3), G_3(x_1,x_2,x_3))\right), $$

and $\Omega=\Omega(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ be a differentiable function on $\mathbb R^3$.
Then, by definition of divergence

$$\operatorname{div}G:=\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{\partial G_i}{\partial x_i}(x_1,x_2,x_3) $$

and so the $j$-th component $\nabla_j(\operatorname{div}G)$ of $\nabla(\operatorname{div}G)$ is given by

$$\nabla_j(\operatorname{div}G)= \sum_{i=1}^3\frac{\partial^2 G_i}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x_1,x_2,x_3),$$

for all $j=1,2,3$. The gradient $\nabla\Omega$ of $\Omega$ has components $\nabla_j\Omega=\frac{\partial\Omega}{\partial x_j}(x_1,x_2,x_3).$

It remains to compute the cross product $\nabla(\operatorname{div}G)\times \nabla\Omega$; this can be done either using the notation

$$\left(\nabla(\operatorname{div}G)\times \nabla\Omega\right)_i = \sum_{j,k=1}^3\epsilon_{ijk} \nabla_j(\operatorname{div}G) \nabla_k\Omega = \text{using the above results} = \sum_{j,k=1}^3\epsilon_{ijk} \left( \sum_{l=1}^3\frac{\partial^2 G_i}{\partial x_l\partial x_j}\right)\frac{\partial\Omega}{\partial x_k},~~~i=1,2,3 $$

where $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the [Levi-Civita antisymmetric tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol), or applying the expansion -component by component - that can be found in [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) at the end of the "Computing cross product" section. The two methods are equivalent.

**On the second expression**.

The methods for the second expression are analogous to the ones shown above. The definition of curl of a vector field is needed: it can be found [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_%28mathematics%29)

Comment: @Emily Peers did it help? Do you need more explanations?